# 'invalid_grant' error on API call with RestSharp

Tags: c#, post, restsharp

I need to convert that curl request to c#. Im using RestSharp. curl request:

```
 > curl -X POST -i https://gw.api.alphabank.eu/sandbox/auth/token \

    -u "{{client_id}}:{{client_secret}}" \

    -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=account-info-setup"
```

I tried the following code but I end up with 'invalid_grant' error as a response.
Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
        var client = new RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest();

        request.Method = Method.POST;
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(ABclientID, ABclientSecret);
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        request.AddParameter("scope", "account-info-setup");

        request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; };

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out "invalid_grant" meant wrong credentials. I was giving wrong client-secret.
Request was succesfull after correcting the client_secret.

Answer (score 1):

this sample code is generated by Postman and it's working for my api which accepts application/x-www-form-urlencoded, can you add your parameters like this? Or create and make your request works on Postman and generate to C#-RestSharp it's usually works for me with minor changes.

```
var client = new RestClient("url");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("userId", "1234");
request.AddParameter("count", "5");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```